# Validação de Dimensão da Imagem com jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery

Mesmo eu selecionando uma imagem nas dimensões corretas está me dando alerta de erro de que não estou selecionando uma imagem nas dimensões certas.

Como faço o retorno dessa função para não entrar no erro ?

### jQuery

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateimg", function(value, element, params){
    var img = new Image();
    var id  = element.id;
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL($('#'+id)[0].files[0]);

    img.onload  = function(){
        var w   = img.naturalWidth;
        var h   = img.naturalHeight;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
        var boo = (w == params[0] && h == params[1]) ? true : false;
        return boo;
    }
});

$("#form-perfil").validate({
   ignore: [],
   errorLabelContainer      : "#error-box-content",
   wrapper                  : 'li',
   rules                    : {
       foto_perfil_admin    :{
          required          : true,
          extension         : "jpg|png",
          validateimg       : [160, 160]
       },
   },
   messages                 : {
        foto_perfil_admin   :{
        required        : 'Escolha uma foto de perfil',
        extension       : 'A foto de perfil do administrador deve ser JPG ou PNG',
        validateimg     : 'Selecione a imagem de perfil do administrador em 160 x 160',
   },
});
```

Acredito que seja pelo fato da variável `boo` estar dentro do *onLoad()*.

E além disso eu tenho vários campos de imagem com a mesma validação e está dando problemas, conflito...

Comment: você já deu um console.log por exemplo nos valores, w == params[0] && h == params[1] ,  pra ver se estão iguais mesmo ?

Comment: Sim, já debuguei tudo...

Comment: realmente é algum problema no load, vou ver se acho a solução

Comment: dê uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785017/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-returns-0-using-onload-event